# Bug in leetcode, javascript 219. Contains Duplicate II

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

This is the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate-ii/

> Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return true if there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that nums[i] == nums[j] and abs(i - j) <= k.

My code:

```
var containsNearbyDuplicate = function(nums, k) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for(let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            console.log([i, j])
            if(nums[i] == nums[j] && Math.abs(i-j) <= k){
                return true;
            } 
        }
    }
    
    return false;
};
```

On submission, I can pass 20/51 cases with status being 'Time Limit Exceeded'.

I can pass the following example inputs:

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1], k = 3
Output: true
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: nums = [1,0,1,1], k = 1
Output: true
```

**Example 3:**

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1,2,3], k = 2
Output: false
```

I can't think of any fringe cases which is causing the submission to exceed time limit. I'm aware that there are other ways to solve this problem, but I would like to know what's wrong with my code.

**EDIT:**

I realised the problem is with this line: console.log([i, j]). If I comment it out, there is no problem with submission. But I'm not quite sure why that line is causing the time limit exceeded error.

Comment: Your code works for me. *Runtime: 8986 ms, faster than 5.04% of JavaScript online submissions for Contains Duplicate II. Memory Usage: 50.4 MB, less than 92.51% of JavaScript online submissions for Contains Duplicate II.*

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance thank you for your comment! I now realised the problem is due to a console.log() error causing the time limit exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leetcode and similar sites often provide *huge* data sets as input. In such cases, an unnecessarily computationally complex algorithm can take too much processing time to complete. That may be what's happening here.

You have a nested loop - if the input array contains 1000 items, that's on the order of 1000 * 1000 iterations. Use a different, less expensive algorithm - such as by iterating over the input only once. One possible approach is

```
var containsNearbyDuplicate = function(nums, k) {
    const numsByLastIndex = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        const num = nums[i];
        if (numsByLastIndex[num] !== undefined && i - numsByLastIndex[num] <= k) {
            return true;
        }
        numsByLastIndex[num] = i;
    }
    return false;
};
```

When I try the above code, the time required has changed from on the order of 9 seconds (which may be close to the limit) down to 1/4 of a second.

Another issue is that logging in the Node CLI, if you do a *ton* of logging, [can slow things down](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242519). Sometimes, logging can even take up most of the processing time of your script. It's not needed to perform the task, so feel free to remove it.